# Insertion order of various child tables in hibernate one to many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem, where I have multiple one to many mapping of multiple childs

```
class parent A{

    List <ChildOne> listOne;

    List <ChildTwo> listTwo,

}
```

Now when performing the insert operation on this class, I want the Child Two entries to be persisted first and then the child one entries in their corresponding tables.

As of now , it is reverse.

So how can i manage this order of insertion of various childs into their corresponding child tables?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you care about the order the inserts happen? Also: If you care so much about minute details of the database interaction you should probably not use an ORM.

Comment: @JensSchauder Because , a trigger gets fired on insertion in the database on the first table, which first checks data in the second table, so by the time ,it gets fired data should be present on the second table before the first table